# Поиск в django при помощи forenkey

Tags: python, django

Возник вопрос есть форма на django где выбираются серийные номера для подачи заявки.
Серийных номеров может быть +100500 в в БД. Подскажите есть ли возможность реализовать поиск в форме Combobox? Или если можно предложите другое решение?

[image: [Форма]]